# swagger bug missing model package

Tags: java, jax-rs, swagger, mustache

i think i found a bug inside swaggers code generation.

I used the example auth.yaml from http://editor.swagger.io/#/
(just go open exmaple, basic auth) and generated jax-rs server code.

```
---
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  version: "1.0.0"
  title: Basic Auth Example
  description: |
    An example for how to use Basic Auth with Swagger.
    Server code is available [here](https://github.com/mohsen1/basic-auth-server). It's running on Heroku.

**User Name and Password**
* User Name: `user`
* Password: `pass`
host: basic-auth-server.herokuapp.com
schemes:
  - http
  - https
securityDefinitions:
  basicAuth:
   type: basic
    description: HTTP Basic Authentication. Works over `HTTP` and `HTTPS`
paths:
  /:
    get:
      security:
   - basicAuth: []
  responses:
    200:
      description:  Will send `Authenticated` if authentication is succesful, otherwise it will send `Unauthorized`
```

Notice: there are no definitons of models.

I tried to compile the generated source but i get errors:

```
error: package ...webservice.jaxrs.model does not exist
```

and its true because there is no folder called model inside the jaxrs folder.
But the package import comes from the mustache files and seems to be generated anyways.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, looks like a bug.  Usually there is at least one input or response model defined and the package import is fine.  But in your case where there are none, it's causing an error.

Comment: When i am not wrong you are one of the swagger devs? Maybe this issue can be fixed?

Comment: Yes, if you could please open an issue on swagger-core it can be addressed.